# SQL Plus/Shell Script: Extra newline printed

Tags: oracle, shell, newline, sqlplus, carriage-return

Below is my variable and the value is being fetched from the query.

```
subsno=`sqlplus -s user/pass@DB << EOL
set heading off;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;

select CFR_SUBSCRIBER_NO
from csm_future_request
where CFR_BAN = 111111111 and cfr_status = 'E' and CFR_SUBSCRIBER_NO<>0000000000;

EOL`
```

But when I am printing this variable it is being printed with a newline first. And the ${#subsno} is printing (length+1), i.e, it is including the new line character.

Is there any option to stop the new line from being printed ? I have already check the table, it has proper data.

Comment: what is the content of `$connstring`?

Comment: you can `echo $subsno | tail +2`

Comment: The query returns only one row. Its a 10 digit number.

Comment: `set newpage none`? (The number of blank lines between the top of each page and the top title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's

```
set newpage none
```

(The number of blank lines between the top of each page and the top title).